# Hadoop: MapReduce MinMax result different from original dataset

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new in Hadoop.
I try to use MapReduce to get the min and max Monthly Precipitation value for each year.
Here is one year of the data set looks like:

```
Product code,Station number,Year,Month,Monthly Precipitation Total (millimetres),Quality
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,01,11.5,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,02,11.4,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,03,20.8,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,04,10.5,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,05,4.8,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,06,90.4,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,07,54.2,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,08,97.4,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,09,41.4,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,10,40.8,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,11,113.2,Y
IDCJAC0001,023000,1839,12,8.9,Y
```

And this is what the result I get for the year 1839:

```
1839    1.31709005E9    1.3172928E9
```

Obviously, the result is not matched to the original data...But I cannot figure out why it happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues.

(1) In `MinMixExposure`, you write doubles, but read ints. You also use Double type (meaning that you care about nulls) but do not handle nulls in serialization/deserialization. If you really need nulls, you should write something like this:

```
// write
out.writeBoolean(value != null);
if (value != null) {
  out.writeDouble(value);
}

// read
if (in.readBoolean()) {
  value = in.readDouble();
} else {
  value = null;
}
```

If you do not need to store nulls, replace `Double` with `double`.

(2) In map function you wrap your code in `IOException` catch blocks. This doesn't make any sense. If input data has records in incorrect format, then most probably you will get `NullPointerException`/`NumberFormatError` in `Double.parseDouble()`. However, you do not handle these exceptions.

Checking for nulls after you called `parseDouble` also doesn't make sense.

(3) You pass map key to reducer as `Text`. I would recommend to pass year as `IntWritable` (and configure your job with `job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);`).

(4) `maxExposure` must be handled similarly to `minExposure` in reducer code. Currently you just return the value for the last record.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic to find the min and max exposure in the Reducer seems off. You set `maxExposure` twice, and never check whether it is actually the max exposure. I'd go with:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<MinMaxExposure> values,
        Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Double minExposure = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    Double maxExposure = Double.MIN_VALUE;

    for (MinMaxExposure val : values) {
        if (val.getMinExposure() < minExposure) {
            minExposure = val.getMinExposure();  
        }

        if (val.getMaxExposure() > maxExposure) {
            maxExposure = val.getMaxExposure();  
        }
    }

    MinMaxExposure resultRow = new MinMaxExposure();
    resultRow.setMinExposure(minExposure);
    resultRow.setMaxExposure(maxExposure);
    context.write(key, resultRow);
}
```